# Go language package structure

Tags: go

I am trying to learn Go and to follow the existing conventions, but, as every convention, you need to first understand them before use them well, and after some research, I didn't find an exact answer to my following question:

I've set up a project inside my `$GOPATH`, following a similar structure like this:

```
$GOPATH/
  github.com/
    username/
      projectname/
        main.go
        numbers/
          rational.go
          real.go
          complex.go
```

My main is:

```
package main

import(
"fmt"
"./numbers"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(numbers.Real{2.0})
}
```

So, the questions are:

1. I read that I need to have a file `package.go` inside each package folder, is that right ?
2. If so, inside `numbers.go`, how will I import `rational.go`, `real.go` and `complex.go` ?
3. And then, is it possible to have something like:

   ```
   // real.go
   package numbers

   type Real struct {
       Number float64
   }
   ```

... and in main do `fmt.Println(numbers.Real{2.0})` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First: Your Setup misses the folder `src`: It should be `$GOPATH/**src**/github.com/..."

Second: Do not use relative imports. Just do not do it. Import package numbers like `import "github.com/username/projectname/number"`

To your questions:

1. No. If you have Go files in a folder the are combined to a package but you are not force to put a package into all folders.
2. All the files `rational.go`, `complex.go` and `real.go` would normally start with `package numbers`. The are all part of package numbers and you do **not** include files but packages. The current package need not be imported. So: No.
3. Yes

Comment: Actually, yes, I'm using `src` and in question number 1 I was actually meaning `packagename.go`, but your help was really helpful and I noticed I just made a silly mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: No, a package foo does not need a file foo.go. A file bar.go with starts with "package foo" is good (but strange).

Comment: "Do not use relative imports", the **Why** please.

Comment: Bad practice, not the intended way, might not work in the future, packages are no longer go get-able. The golang mailing list is full of details. Or take a look here https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6147 .