# Is it possible don't specify package name?

Tags: go

Here is an example of my code:

```
package main

import (
  "./bio"
)

func main() {
   bio.PeptideEncoding(genome, codonTable)
}
```

Is it possible to use functions from my paxkage (bio) without specifying package name:

```
func main() {
   PeptideEncoding(genome, codonTable)
}
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use as an [import declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) like:

```
. "./bio"
```

> If an explicit period (`.`) appears instead of a name, all the package's exported identifiers declared in that package's package block will be declared in the importing source file's file block and **must be accessed without a qualifier**.

That is what a [testing framework like govey does](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/wiki#get-going-in-25-seconds):

```
package package_name

import (
    "testing"
    . "github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey"
)

func TestIntegerStuff(t *testing.T) {
    Convey("Given some integer with a starting value", t, func() {
        x := 1

        Convey("When the integer is incremented", func() {
            x++

            Convey("The value should be greater by one", func() {
                So(x, ShouldEqual, 2)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

You don't need to use `convey.So()`, or `convey.Convey()` because of the import starting with  a '`.`'.

Don't abuse it though, since, as [twotwotwo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2714852/twotwotwo) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816151/is-it-possible-dont-specify-package-name/26816170?noredirect=1#comment42215024_26816170), The **[style guide](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments#Import_Dot)** discourages it outside of tests.

> Except for this one case, do not use `import .` in your programs.
>   It makes the programs much harder to read because it is unclear whether a name like Quux is a top-level identifier in the current package or in an imported package.

That is why I mentioned a *testing* framework using this technique.

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816151/is-it-possible-dont-specify-package-name/26816170?noredirect=1#comment42203822_26816170) by [Simon Whitehead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517578/simon-whitehead), using **relative import** is not generally considered as the best practice (see for instance "[Go language package structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21616792/6309)").

You should also import the package via the `GOPATH` instead of relatively, as show in "[Import and not used error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25924797/6309)".

Comment: @SimonWhitehead true. I have edited the answer to point out that questionable import usage.

Comment: The style guide discourages it outside of tests: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments#Import_Dot

Comment: @twotwotwo indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.