# use custom Go packages

Tags: go, package

I have written some custom packages which I am struggling to reuse.

My code is structured as follows:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/myusername/myfirstrepo/
```

In `myfirstrepo` I have 2 different packages:

```
myfirstrepo
   |--somefolder1/package1
   |--somefolder2/package2
```

Now I'd like to import my `package1` in `package2`, I know I can use my published code on github using `go get` but I'd like to know if it's possible to use something similar to `npm`:

```
import "./../somefolder1/package1"
```

Obviously I've tried this and it doesn't work.

How can I simply do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I'd like to import my `package1` in `package2`, I know I can use my published code on github using `go get`

It doesn't have to be published on github.
The import path just has to be a valid path within your **[workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)** (`$GOPATH`)

```
import "github.com/myusername/myfirstrepo/somefolder1/package1"
```

Relative paths are [not the best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21616792/6309) (unless you really need to [access your functions without classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26816170/6309)).